# Problemas para insertar datos en una tabla que tengo que coger de otra tabla a partir del id SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Veamos, tengo dos tablas en MySQL. Una se llama proveedores y otra se llama artículos nuevos. En ambas tengo los siguientes campos: ean, proveedor, marca, categoria, nombre y precio. El ean es la primary key. El caso es que ahora mismo tengo en artículos nuevos un listado de eans, y a partir de ellos quiero recuperar el resto de datos (los otros campos) que están en proveedores. Estoy liado con la sintaxis que tengo que hacer. A ver, yo ahora mismo haría algo así:

```
$sql="UPDATE articulos nuevos SET `proveedor`= WHERE (SELECT `proveedor` FROM proveedores WHERE `ean`=$ean) SET `marca` WHERE (SELECT `marca` FROM proveedores WHERE `ean`=$ean) SET `categoria WHERE (SELECT `categoria` FROM proveedores WHERE `ean`=$ean) SET `nombre` WHERE (SELECT `nombre` FROM proveedores WHERE `ean`=$ean) SET `precio` WHERE (SELECT `precio` FROM proveedores WHERE `ean`=$ean)
```

El problema es que veo la sentencia super larga y pienso que quizás hay una forma mejor de hacerla, además de que no tengo nada claro que a nivel de sintaxis funcione. ¿Alguna idea? Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres actualizar una tabla a partir de los datos de otra, construye tu sentencia SQL primero con el `SET` de todos los campos y luego indica la relación entre ambas tablas, en este caso cono un `INNER JOIN`.

Te indico solo la sentencia SQL, para mayor claridad, y tu mismo la puedes poner en el string $sql.

```
UPDATE articulos SET `proveedor`= b.`proveedor`,
`marca`= b.`marca`, `categoria`= b.`categoria`, `nombre`= b.`nombre`,
`precio`= b.`precio`
FROM articulos
INNER JOIN proveedores b ON articulos.`ean` = b.`ean`
WHERE b.`ean`= $ean
```